# Почему не работает метод .lower()?

Tags: python

Почему метод .lower() не работает в этом коде, когда я ввожу слова Да с заглавной, он не делает все буквы в нижний регистр

```
        while True:
            choice = input(f'{name} хотите открыть калькулятор(введите: да/нет):')
            choice.lower()
            if choice == 'да':
                print(get_calculator_kbju(set_data()))
                break
            elif choice == 'нет':
                print(f'{name} Welcome')
                break
            else:
                print('Введите да/нет')
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что надо так

```
choice = choice.lower()
```

возвращаемое значение в нижнем регистре, а не исходное

> Возвращает копию исходной строки с символами приведёнными к нижнему
> регистру.
>
> str.lower() -> str

Comment: Спасибо, что то затупил просто(

Answer (score 0):

Или можете заменить строку `choice = input(f'{name} хотите открыть калькулятор(введите: да/нет):')` на `choice = input(f'{name} хотите открыть калькулятор(введите: да/нет):').lower()`, короче будет